# MySQL Databases suddenly gone. "QQ_83191575"

Tags: mysql, database

So I am the owner of a Minecraft network, and last night upon looking through console I am seeing errors from many of my plugins that are claiming that the database they require are missing, and upon logging into PhpMyAdmin, I see that all of my databases are gone, however there was one database that was there that I know for a fact I did not create, it was named "QQ_83191575" at first I thought we were hacked, so I loaded by backups and generated a 25+ character password only to find out this morning that the same exact thing happened with the same database and everything.   I was curious if anyone knew anything about this?  Thank you :)

Comment: That is not common database name and moving around data files in the way you describe is very unusual.

Comment: Can you provide more information on how the MySQL server is hosted and if there are any other sites/services connecting to the server? You may be vulnerable to a MySQL injection attack f there are any exposed endpoints.

Comment: The only external connections I have to the machine are my Amazon EC2 server which is running my Xenforo website.  I saw earlier someone posted a thread also claiming the exact same thing happened to them on their Amazon EC2 server as well with the same database and everything, so I'm wondering if it has something to do with Amazon, it's still odd that another user claimed the same thing happened to them only hours after me and they also were using Amazon.

Comment: It points to you being hacked. Which OS are you running and which kernel version? It appears as if someone gained remote access and simply ruined your database. Since it happened more than once with exact symptoms, it means someone other than you did something and it's definitely not some random Amazon feature.

Comment: Just noticed it happened to my MySQL instance on Linode within the last 8h, so not AWS-exclusive! I've concluded remote exploit, running on Debian 8.6 up to date. It's running a Wordpress up-to-date site.

Comment: That's really odd, So it appears that it was a mass hacking then.   The worst part is my machine is running the most recent updates of Ubuntu.   I hope this is resolved as it's happened to me twice now with 24 hours

Answer (score 2):

My private mysql database is also attacked by the same guy early this morning. He also created the same database as QQ_83191575, and all my other database were disappeared. The created database name is his QQ number, one of Chinese local social app. I find his information by his Chinese Tencent QQ number of 83191575. He is from China and he requests money to restore the database, but I don't trust him. 
[image]
His avatar is the mask in movie "V for Vendetta", however, it is a shame of his action to blackmail civilian with his technical skill.

Comment: What I did as following for remedies:

Comment: 1. Close the 3306 public port immediately.

Comment: 2. User iptables command to create rules only enable certain ip address to access the 3306 port from LAN or WAN; 3. Build up SSL authentication to enable security of the mysql client access; 4. Restore the previous backup databases; 5. Build up regular database backup strategies; 6. Make sure everything is OK, then reopen the public port for secure access.

Answer (score 1):

Our lab's 'mariadb' was also hacked by him yesterday.

I think there's no evidence that ssh was cracked, and it's impossible to get sql injection. All db tables were gone but his signature table, QQ_83191575.

I find our 3306 port had been opened to public, that's maybe a clue.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me yesterday. :(

I **strongly** believe that phpmyadmin is the blame. The 5 GB database that he deleted was on a server with only mysql and redis. However I was using phpmyadmin from another server to manage the database and I had port 3306 open to the public. The password with phpmyadmin was only with cookie. Password was a 30 character generated string.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same attack. I found out that the root/% had no password. So the hacker must used an SQL injection to set the root password to null and gained remote access.

Close port 3306 from firewall and remove all MySQL users that has remote access privileges. Remove all DBs and tables from MySQL database that aren't yours and then restore your databases.